# Android get parsed data back to activity

Tags: java, android, android-listview, arraylist, plist

I'm trying to parse a plist file, and as I see in log cat I'm doing that good, but when I try to return the arraylist that contains the objects I have parsed it gives me null(by this I mean that my object has an arraylist as parameter, and those arraylists are null). Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Here is my parser:

```
public class XmlMapParser {

    private final static String CAT = "Category";
    private final static String TITLE_AR = "TitleAr";
    private final static String TITLE_FR = "TitleFr";
    private final static String TITLE_EN = "TitleEn";

    private final static String DESC_FR = "DescriptionFr";
    private final static String DESC_AR = "DescriptionAr";
    private final static String DESC_EN = "DescriptionEn";
    private final static String DESC_PH = "DescriptionPh";

    private XmlPullParser parser;
    private ArrayList<String> ar, en, ph, fr;
    private ArrayList<MyObjectFinal> parsedElements;
    private String category, titleAr, titleFr, titleEn;

    public XmlMapParser(Context context, int xmlid) {
        parser = context.getResources().getXml(xmlid);
        ar = new ArrayList<String>();
        fr = new ArrayList<String>();
        ph = new ArrayList<String>();
        en = new ArrayList<String>();
        parsedElements = new ArrayList<MyObjectFinal>();
    }

    public HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> convert() {
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

        final String KEY = "key", STRING = "string";

        try {
            parser.next();
            int eventType = parser.getEventType();
            String lastTag = null;
            String lastKey = null;

            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

                if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    lastTag = parser.getName();
                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                    // some text

                    if (KEY.equalsIgnoreCase(lastTag)) {
                        // start tracking a new key
                        lastKey = parser.getText();
                    } else if (STRING.equalsIgnoreCase(lastTag)) {
                        // a new string for the last encountered key
                        if (!map.containsKey(lastKey)) {
                            map.put(lastKey, new ArrayList<String>());
                        }
                        try {
                            if (lastKey.equals("Category")) {
                                category = parser.getText();
                                Log.v("--", "OBJECT DA " + ar.size());
                                parsedElements.add(new MyObjectFinal(category,
                                        titleEn, titleFr, titleAr, ar, en, fr,
                                        ph));
                                Log.v("--", "Adding cat:" + category + " tit:"
                                        + titleEn + " descEn" + en.size()
                                        + " desckAr:" + ar.size());
                                ar.clear();
                                en.clear();
                                ph.clear();
                                fr.clear();
                                category = null;
                                titleAr = null;
                                titleFr = null;
                                titleEn = null;
                            } else {
                                if (lastKey.equals(DESC_AR)) {
                                    ar.add(parser.getText());
                                }
                                if (lastKey.equals(DESC_FR))
                                    fr.add(parser.getText());
                                if (lastKey.equals(DESC_EN))
                                    en.add(parser.getText());
                                if (lastKey.equals(DESC_PH))
                                    ph.add(parser.getText());
                                if (lastKey.equals(CAT))
                                    category = parser.getText();
                                if (lastKey.equals(TITLE_EN))
                                    titleEn = parser.getText();
                                if (lastKey.equals(TITLE_FR))
                                    titleFr = parser.getText();
                                if (lastKey.equals(TITLE_AR))
                                    titleAr = parser.getText();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        map.get(lastKey).add(parser.getText());
                    }
                }

                eventType = parser.next();
            }
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return map;
    }

    public int parsedElementsSize() {
        return parsedElements.size();
    }

    public ArrayList<MyObjectFinal> getParsedElements() {
        return parsedElements;
    }
```

And I'm getting size 0 by doing this `myXmlParser.getParsedElements().get(0).getDescriptionEn().size();`

Comment: add your parsing logs

Comment: @njzk2 as I see them there are fine and the logs are very long, so I'm thinking that maybe im having the problem elsewhere, like reseting the arraylist of myobjectfinal, not initializing etc..

Comment: the problem is `en.clear();`. you are confusing copying an object and assigning it to a reference.

Comment: @njzk2 hmm. im not sure that I understand, I do the clear so the next object will have empty arraylist. What do you suggest?

Comment: you need to create a new array each time, since all your parsedElements can't use the same instance.

Comment: @njzk2 ok ill try that now

Comment: @njzk2 thanks alot that is the solution. Please submit your answer  for me to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently using only one instance of `ArrayList` for all your `MyObjectFinal` instances, as shown by the use of `en.clear();` (also applies to the other array lists used in `MyObjectFinal`).

That means that when you `en.clear();`, you clear the content of the `ArrayList` for all the instances of the `MyObjectFinal`.

You need to create a new instance of `ArrayList` for each instance of `MyObjectFinal`, like so:

```
en = new ArrayList<>();
```

instead of

```
en.clear();
```